# Showing that $\alpha\geq \beta$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, supremum-and-infimum

Let $\mathcal{B}(F)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators on a complex Hilbert space $F$.

Let $A,B\in \mathcal{B}(F)$. Consider the following numbers:
$$\alpha=\sup_{\substack{a,b\in \mathbb{C}^2,\\ |a|^2+|b|^2<1}}\sup\{|\mu|\,;\;\mu\in \sigma(aA+bB)\}.$$
$$\beta=\sup\{\lambda^{1/2}\,;\;\lambda\in \sigma(A^*A+B^*B)\},$$
where $\sigma(X)$ is the spectrum of an operator $X$.

> I want to show that
>   $$\alpha\geq \beta.$$

Comment: Your title should be more descriptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality does not hold. Take $A$ any nonzero nilpotent element, and $B=0$. Then $\alpha=0$ and $\beta=\|A\|$.

The reverse inequality does hold, though. We have 
\begin{align}
\operatorname{spr}(aA+bB)^2
&\leq \|aA+bB\|^2\leq (|a|\,\|A\|+|b|\,\|B\|)^2.
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
\sup_{a,b}\operatorname{spr}(aA+bB)^2
&\leq\sup_{a,b}(|a|\,\|A\|+|b|\,\|B\|)^2=\max\{\|A\|^2,\|B\|^2\}\\
&=\max\{\|A^*A\|,\|B^*B\|\}\\
&\leq \|A^*A+B^*B\|\\
&=\sup\{\lambda:\ \lambda\in\sigma(A^*A+B^*B)\}\\
&=\sup\{\lambda^{1/2}:\ \lambda\in\sigma(A^*A+B^*B)\}^2\\
\end{align}
So 
$$
\alpha\leq\beta.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. If $A$ and $B$ are commuting normal operator, I think that the inequality holds.

Comment: No, if you take $B=A$, the inequality is always strict